# Firebase query based off results of another query

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a dropdown button that has a list of names.
The dropdown should show the name of the athletes for the teams.
However, the dropdown is only showing the UID. I am unable to have it query the accounts by the UID to pull the proper name.

Code:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: database.reference().child("teams").child("TID1").child("athletes").once(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      aKeys.clear();
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
      values.forEach((key, value) {
        database.reference().child("accounts").child(value).once();
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> nameValues = snapshot.data.value;
          nameValues.forEach((key, value) {
            aNames.add(
              DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
                child: Text(value["first name"]),
                value: key,
              )
            );
          });
        }
      });
      return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
            items: aNames,
            hint: Text("Select an athlete"),
            value: _athlete,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _athlete = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
),
```

I know the problem lies within the values.forEach as that's where I'm trying to run the query on the accounts to pull the name. I know that is not working because it is not the proper way, but I don't know the proper way to get it working. I tried adding another FutureBuilder inside of the values.forEach but that did not work either.

I figured do a query to find out what the athlete keys for the teams are, then throw those into a list. Then iterate through that list to run the query on accounts to then get the first name values and add that to a separate list that has the DropdownMenuItem with the first names.

JSON data:

```
{
    "accounts" :{
        "UID1" : {
            "first name" : "bob",
            "last name" :  "rogers"
        },
        "UID2" : {
            "first name" : "john",
            "last name" : "smith"
        },
        "UID3" : {
            "first name" : "tim",
            "last name" : "murr"
        },
        "UID4" : {
            "first name" : "larry",
            "last name" : "dean"
        }
    },
    "teams" : {
        "TID1" : {
            "athletes" : {
                "A1" : "UID1",
                "A2" : "UID2"
            }
        },
        "TID2" : {
            "athletes" : {
                "A1" : "UID3",
                "A2" : "UID4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current Code:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: database.reference().child("teams").child("UID").child("athletes").once(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      dynamic values = snapshot.data.value;
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.wait<DataSnapshot>(values.map((key, value) {
          return database.reference().child("accounts").child(value).once();
        })),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DataSnapshot>> snapshots) {
          snapshots.data!.forEach((snapshot) {
            aNames.add(
                DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
                  child: Text(snapshot.value["first name"]),
                  value: snapshot.key,
                )
            );
          });
          return Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
                items: aNames,
                hint: Text("Select an athlete"),
                value: _athlete,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _athlete = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You're no handling the `Future` that is returned by `once()` in your calls to:

```
database.reference().child("accounts").child(value).once();
```

If you have to retrieve only one account, you could use another `FutureBuilder` with that `once()` call as the `future` property, same as you do now for:

```
future: database.reference().child("teams").child("TID1").child("athletes").once()
```

But since you have multiple `once()`, you will have to gather all of those and then pass then to [`Future.wait()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html).

Something like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: database.reference().child("teams").child("TID1").child("athletes").once(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.wait(values.map((key, value) {
          return database.reference().child("accounts").child(value).once();
        }
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DataSnapshot>> snapshots) {
          snapshots.data!.forEach((snapshot) {
            // TODO: get the value from the snapshot and create your dropdown with it
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
),
```

*I did not run this code, so there may be some minor problems in there. The crux of my answer is: you'll need to use `Future.wait` and another `FutureBuilder` to handle the multiple `once` calls.*

Comment: Hey I am still having trouble getting this to work, would greatly appreciate some more hlep

Comment: "I am still having trouble" That's hard to help with. What did you do with the information in my answer, and what problem did you get?

Comment: I used what you put and essentially added what was missing from my original, the add of the dropdownMenuItem and the Material return of the actual DropdownButton. That was giving red error lines throughout the entire inner FutureBuilder and I couldn't get those to go away without changing the inner builder AsyncSnapshot<List<DataSnapshot>> to AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>.
But the problem then was that the line `Map<dynamic,dynamic> nameValues = snapshots.data.value;` says .value is not defined for List<dynamic>.

Comment: I can go on a bit more about what I did next if you want, but from there I had changed the List<dynamic> to DataSnapshot and had taken away the future.wait in order to actually be able to run the app. But I knew I wasn't doing something right since I had to take away the future.wait to get it to run.

Comment: Using `dynamic` is not a good solution. Did you try `Future.wait< DataSnapshot>(values.map(...`? Also: always check and share the exact error message you get, as that's gonna be useful to understand the problem.

Comment: I just tried the `Future.wait<DataSnpshot>(values.map(...` the error is still on the `Map<dynamic,dynamic> nameValues = snapshots.data.value;` line. The error message it is giving me in the console its `Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'List<DataSnapshot>'.`

Comment: Also I am not using the `snapshots.forEach((snapsot) ...` as it was also returning a error on the forEach. `Error: The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncSnapshot<List<DataSnapshot>>'.`. I am going to paste my current code in the question to hopefully make this easier.

Comment: Ah, that might indeed be `snapshots.data!.forEach((snapshot) {...`.

Comment: Okay that is now working, I changed the code to what it is above and the app runs but its returning an error. `type '(dynamic, dynamic) => Future<DataSnapshot>' is not a subtype of type '(Object?, Object?) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'`. I don't even know what is causing this.